# select statement with multiple AND operators on the same column

Tags: sql, select

I use DB2.

Situation: I want do do a query on my table RELATIONS to list ALL the companies that have a RELATION 1 AND a RELATION 2 OR 3 assigned. In my DB design, 1 or more companies could have multiple relations.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? DB2? Firebird?

Comment: you might probably need to show your sample data and expected result

Answer (score 0):

Try below query

```
SELECT * from RELATIONS
WHERE COMPANY_ID = 2245
AND RELATION_ID in (4,5,6)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can.  But the action is meaningless, because you cannot have a row where the column is "4" and also "5"/"6".  If you were looking for any of them, then you would just add the value to the `in` list:

```
SELECT *
FROM RELATIONS
WHERE COMPANY_ID = 2245 AND RELATION_ID IN (4, 5, 6);
```

But that is not what you want.  You want to get values from *different* rows.  One method uses aggregation:

```
select company_id
from relations r
where relation_id in (4, 5, 6)
group by company_id
having sum(case when relation_id = 4 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when relation_id in (5, 6) then 1 else 0 end) > 0;
```

Comment: @snorkel . . . You changed the question.  This is for companies that have relation 4 and either 5 or 6.